# Android prompt notification automatically code

Tags: java, android

here I'm try to develop an Android application which will prompt the user notification as reminder automatically. The notification prompts to user when meet certain condition.

For my case, the application is like personal recorder application, it requires the user to record data everyday. If whole day the application detects there is no data entry, it will prompt a reminder at a specific time to remind the user to launch the application and enter data.

For example, at 10.00pm, the user never launch the application for that day, the application will prompt a reminder "Please make sure that the data is updated!".

How the code work? I have refer many tutorial but seem not I want. Thank you.

Comment: You may not find the solution of your problem directly. But you can merge your findings and prepare a solution. One suggested is like - Schedule a pendingIntent with alarmmanager @ 10.00 pm, to open broadcast receiver in your application, which will start a server for adding reminder Notification. Now if user does the data update before 10 pm then cancel the scheduled alarm and schedule one new for next day 10 pm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android documentation suggests that you should use [Alarm Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to register an Intent that will fire at the specified time if your application may not be running.

And when that happens, fire your notification.

```
m_notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(textMessage)
                .setSubText(subTextMessage)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_notification)
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 100});
```

Use notification manager to notify after you have constructed your notification.